# How can we join diffrent two datatype values SQL

Tags: sql

**Table1:**

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | INAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Smith | 1st | 09-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | P |

**Table2:**

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | INAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Smith | 1st | 10-12-2022 | Absent | A |

**Table3:**

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | INAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Smith | 1st | 09-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | P |
| 1001 | Smith | 1st | 10-12-2022 | Absent | A |

I have two tables 'Table1' column Intime datatype is **'Time7'** and 'Table2' column Intime datatype is **varchar**. These column names(Intime) same but, datatypes are different. Could someone suggest me how to sql join these tables and get result is Table3.

Comment: Inconsistent table design. Fix it, and your JOiN will be fine.

Comment: What do yo mean by "join"? According to your description, the result will just be built using UNION ALL, without any JOIN. It seems you are missing to provide some important details?

Comment: @JonasMetzler, when I try to join two table I'm getting error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Each database engine is a little different. "SQL" is a query language which is implemented slightly differently by each product.

Comment: @Smith You didn't answer my question. Why/how do you want to join here? According to your sample data, "select * from table1 union all select * from table2" (would be better to use column names than *, I just shortened it) will produce the result you've shown. So did you miss to tell us something important?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said these should probably be the same data types in the database but you may be able to convert the data type on the join.

```
on convert(varchar(50),A.intime) = convert(varchar(50),B.intime)
```

Comment: SELECT
Table1.ID,Table1.Name,Table1.Class,table1.Date,Table1.Intime,Table1.INAM,
Table2.ID,Table2.Name,Table2.Class,table2.Date,Table2.Intime,Table2.INAM

FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON  convert(varchar(50),table1.intime) = convert(varchar(50),table2.intime) It's showing 0 records where I got worng. Thank you